# Getting 'Solution file error MSB5014' while installing a node package

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-gyp

I'm trying to install a node package for bot test framework called 'botium-cli' using the below command:

```
npm install -g botium-cli
```

on a windows server machine (Windows Server 2008).

I've been repeatedly getting different flavors of node-gyp errors.
I know that node-gyp issues are very popular on various forums, and I have tried plenty of suggestions, but the errors just don't go away.

I have tried the following so far:

- Uninstall and re-install node-gyp
- Uninstall and re-install nodeJS
- Upgrade nodeJS version
- Install python v2.7
- Install MSBuild tools using command 'npm install --global --production windows-build-tools'
- Set msvs_version to 2015 in npm config

I'm with this issue for more than 5-7 days, and I have been trying to install this package on 4 different machines, but node-gyp always comes in the way.

The highlighted portion in the error message is:

> build/binding.sln(1): Solution file error MSB5014: File format version
>   is not recognized.  MSBuild can only read solution files between
>   versions 7.0 and 9.0, inclusive.

Below is the complete log of error:

```
> > npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.5.2: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
> C:\Users\dkarkala\AppData\Roaming\npm\botium-cli ->
> C:\Users\dkarkala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\botium-cli\bin\botium-cli.js
> 
> > grpc@1.11.3 install C:\Users\dkarkala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\botium-cli\node_modules\dialogflow\node_modules\grpc
> > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
> 
> node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(400):
> https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.11.3/node-v57-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
> 
> node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.11.3 and
> node@8.11.2 (node-v57 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile
> with node-gyp)
> 
> build/binding.sln(1): Solution file error MSB5014: File format version
> is not recognized.  MSBuild can only read solution files between
> versions 7.0 a nd 9.0, inclusive. gyp ERR! build error gyp ERR! stack
> Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1 gyp ERR! stack     at
> ChildProcess.onExit
> (C:\Users\dkarkala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
> gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13) gyp ERR! stack     at
> ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7) gyp ERR! stack     at
> Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
> gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601 gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program
> Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"
> "C:\\Users\\dkarkala\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\no
> de-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
> "--module=C:\\Users\\dkarkala\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\botium-cli\\no
> de_modules\\dialogflow\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node"
> "--module_name=grpc_node" "--modu
> le_path=C:\\Users\\dkarkala\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\botium-cli\\node_modules\\dialogflow\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binar
> y\\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=3"
> "--node_abi_napi=napi" gyp ERR! cwd
> C:\Users\dkarkala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\botium-cli\node_modules\dialogflow\node_modules\grpc
> gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.2 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2 gyp ERR! not ok
> node-pre-gyp ERR! build error node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to
> execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
> C:\Users\dkarkala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules
> \node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build
> --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\dkarkala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\botium-cli\no
> de_modules\dialogflow\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node
> --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\U sers\dkarkala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\botium-cli\node_modules\dialogflow\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unkno
> wn --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1) node-pre-gyp ERR! stack 
> at ChildProcess.<anonymous>
> (C:\Users\dkarkala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\botium-cli\node_modules\dialogflow\node_mo
> dules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13) node-pre-gyp
> ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7) node-pre-gyp
> ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
> node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit
> (internal/child_process.js:209:5) node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT
> 6.1.7601 node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"
> "C:\\Users\\dkarkala\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\botium-cli\\node_modules\\d
> ialogflow\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp"
> "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
> node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd
> C:\Users\dkarkala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\botium-cli\node_modules\dialogflow\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.2 node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v
> v0.10.0 node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok Failed to execute 'C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node.exe
> C:\Users\dkarkala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js
> build  --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
> --module=C:\Users\dkarkala\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\botium-cli\node_modules\dialogflow\node_modu
> les\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node
> --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\dkarkala\AppData\Roaming\n pm\node_modules\botium-cli\node_modules\dialogflow\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v57-win32-x64-unknown
> --napi_version=3 --node_abi_ napi=napi' (1) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! grpc@1.11.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install
> --fallback-to-build --library=static_library` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.11.3 install script. npm ERR!
> This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional
> logging output above.
> 
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!    
> C:\Users\dkarkala\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-05-16T12_31_16_928Z-debug.log
```

**Edit:**
I'm getting the exact same issue while trying to install below package as well:

```
npm i dialogflow --save
```

Comment: The first major problem in that error log is the failure to download the prebuilt binary file. That file does exist, and I'm not sure why that would fail like that. Are you perhaps unable to access storage.googleapis.com?

Comment: node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(400):
> https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.11.3/node-v57-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gzSince it was marked as a WARNING, i assumed

Comment: node-pre-gyp marks that as a warning because it falls back to trying to build from source, but the grpc library in particular is a giant pain to build from source on Windows.

Comment: Oh thanks for the info. From browser, I'm able to access this site, which downloads the file 'node-v57-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz'. Any idea if this file is useful in any way to solve the problem?